Coverage does not work when using Istanbul
If I run vitest run --coverage when using default's v8 system, everything works, and I get a proper text table with the coverage. But if I use now Istanbul instead, I get an error:
> 2024-03-sveltekit@0.0.1 coverage
> VITE_COVERAGE=true vitest run --coverage

23:55:17 [vite-plugin-svelte] You are using Svelte 5.0.0-next.123. Svelte 5 support is experimental, breaking changes can occur in any release until this notice is removed.
work in progress:
 - svelte-inspector is disabled until dev mode implements node to code mapping


 RUN  v1.6.0 /home/leo/Documents/Informatique/Programmation/Projects/2023_05_15_-_Maman_planning/web_interface/2024_03_sveltekit
      Coverage enabled with istanbul

(node:1338588) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:1338588) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
stdout | src/routes/home.test.js:21:9
en-US

 ✓ src/lib/database/db.test.js (9)
 ✓ src/routes/home.test.js (1)

 Test Files  2 passed (2)
      Tests  10 passed (10)
   Start at  23:55:17
   Duration  2.41s (transform 1.10s, setup 1ms, collect 2.23s, tests 53ms, environment 646ms, prepare 175ms)


⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯ Unhandled Error ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
Error: Failed to resolve import "$app/stores" from "src/routes/file/[fileUuid]/+page.svelte?v=1718315720519". Does the file exist?
1267|  $.mark_module_start();
1268|  import * as $ from "svelte/internal/client";
1269|  import { page } from "$app/stores";
   |                        ^

Do you know how to fix this?
I have so far:
vitest.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';
import { resolve, dirname } from 'node:path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url'
import { configDefaults } from 'vitest/config'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    exclude:[
      ...configDefaults.exclude, 
      '.direnv',
      'tests/playwright/**/*'
    ],
    coverage: {
      provider: 'istanbul', // or 'v8'
      reporter: ['text']
    },
    environment: 'jsdom',
    alias: [
      {
        find: /\$lib/,
        replacement: resolve(fileURLToPath(dirname(import.meta.url)), '/src/lib'),
      }
    ]
  }
});

vite.config.ts
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import istanbul from 'vite-plugin-istanbul';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
    sveltekit(),
    istanbul({
      include: 'src/*',
      exclude: ['node_modules', 'tests/'],
      extension: ['.js', '.ts', '.svelte'],
      // VITE_COVERAGE=true to enable the plugin
      requireEnv: true
    }),
  ]
});

